# apt error while insalling application

Tags: 11.10, apt, synaptic, phpmyadmin

I tried to install `phpmyadmin` from synaptic.
after successfull installation I noticed the config file is empty so I removed it and tried to install it again but I got this error:

```
 no type given for question at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 22, <GEN1> line 2.
 dpkg: error processing phpmyadmin (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 29
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  phpmyadmin
```

now I can't install anything! it continues giving the error to me.

What's the problem?

Comment: Please post the result of `dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii | tail -n+6` so we can see what packages are broken.

Answer (score 0):

When you use dpkg it leaves uncompleted jobs:

- See the processes by `ps -e`.
- Kill those using the installer with `kill <PID>`, then try to install again.